# doing a search of the database python/flask no sql

Tags: html, python-2.7, flask

I am trying to get a search function working. I have a database using excel and would like to be able to search it while on the go. I am stuck trying to get the search form working. Below is the code in python for the form:

```
from forms import ComicSearchForm

@app.route('/make_search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():

    search = ComicSearchForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'GET, POST':
        return search_results(result)

    return render_template('search.html', form=search)


@app.route('/search')
# @login required
def search_results(result):
    bob = create_bob('*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*')
    bobby = []
    current_page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    per_page = 10
    end = (current_page * per_page) + 1
    if end > len(bob):
        end = len(bob)
    start = ((current_page - 1) * per_page) + 1

    sort_bob = sorted(bob, key=lambda v: (v.issue_type, v.publisher, v.sort, v.character, v.volume, v.issues,
                                          v.publication_date))
    if datetime.strptime(sort_bob[0][7], '%B, %Y') >= datetime.now():
        sort_bob = sorted(sort_bob, key=lambda v: (v.publication_date, '%B, %Y'))

        for result in bob[start:end]:
            if result.bob.series_title == str.find(''):
                bobby.append(result)
    next = str(current_page + 1) if end < len(bob) else '0'
    prev = str(current_page - 1)

    if not result:
        flash('No results found!')
        return redirect('make_search')
    else:
        # display results
        return render_template('search.html', bobby=bobby, header=original_header, next=next, prev=prev)
```

Here is the form:

```
from wtforms import Form, StringField, SelectField


class ComicSearchForm(Form):
    choices = [('Series Title', 'Series Title'),
                ('Author', 'Author'),
                ('Artist', 'Artist'),
                ('Publisher', 'Publisher'),
                ('Publication Date', 'Publication Date')]
    select = SelectField('Search for comics:', choices=choices)
    search = StringField('')
```

I am stuck trying to figure out:

```
for result in bob[start:end]:
            if result.bob.series_title == str.find(''):
                bobby.append(result)
```

This is where i am currently think this needs work. I would love some ideas of where i need to go to make this work.

Thanks,

Zach

Comment: What is not working. Do you get an error, unexpected behavior. A missing feature? If so, be specific.

Comment: I cant get anything to happen when i try and input any words into the text box.